# Как передать аргументы в функцию поотдельности?

Tags: python, функции, telegram, aiogram

Пишу бота на aiogram с midjourney и api thenextleg.
Есть такой код бота.

```
@dp.message_handler(state=Form.image)
async def process_name(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['description'] = message.text
    print(data['description'])
    testreal.main(data['description'])
    photo = open(data['description'] + '.jpg', 'rb')
    await bot.send_photo(chat_id=message.chat.id, photo=photo)
    await message.answer(f"Хорошо")
    await message.answer(f"Теперь выбери версию")
    await Form.image2.set()

@dp.message_handler(state=Form.image2)
async def process_start(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    if message.text == "1":
        photo = open(data['description'] + 'var.jpg', 'rb')
        await bot.send_photo(chat_id=message.chat.id, photo=photo)
        await message.answer(f"Вы выбрали эту картинку")
        await Form.req.set()
    elif message.text == "2":
        photo = open(data['description'] + 'var.jpg', 'rb')
        await bot.send_photo(chat_id=message.chat.id, photo=photo)
        await message.answer(f"Вы выбрали эту картинку")
        await Form.req.set()
    elif message.text == "3":
        photo = open(data['description'] + 'var.jpg', 'rb')
        await bot.send_photo(chat_id=message.chat.id, photo=photo)
        await message.answer(f"Вы выбрали эту картинку")
        await Form.req.set()
```

И такая функция для получения изображения

```
def main(prompt,version):
    # Generate the image
    image_res = requests.post(
        f"{BASE_URL}/imagine", headers=AUTH_HEADERS, json={"msg": prompt}
    )
    image_response_data = image_res.json()
    print("\n=====================")
    print("IMAGE GENERATION MESSAGE DATA")
    print(image_response_data)
    print("=====================")

    completed_image_data = fetch_to_completion(image_response_data["messageId"], 0)

    print("\n=====================")
    print("COMPLETED IMAGE DATA")
    print(completed_image_data)
    print("=====================")

    # Save the completed image
    image_url = completed_image_data["response"]["imageUrl"]
    save_image_from_url(image_url, prompt + '.jpg')

    print("Saved completed image as" + prompt + ".jpg")

    # Now, ask the user to input the version

    # Invoke the user-specified version
    variation_res = requests.post(
        f"{BASE_URL}/button",
        headers=AUTH_HEADERS,
        json={
            "button": version,
            "buttonMessageId": completed_image_data["response"]["buttonMessageId"],
        },
    )
    variation_response_data = variation_res.json()
    print("\n=====================")
    print("IMAGE VARIATION MESSAGE DATA")
    print(variation_response_data)
    print("=====================")

    completed_variation_data = fetch_to_completion(
        variation_response_data["messageId"], 0
    )

    print("\n=====================")
    print("COMPLETED VARIATION DATA")
    print(completed_variation_data)
    print("=====================")

    # Save the completed variation image
    image_url = completed_variation_data["response"]["imageUrl"]
    save_image_from_url(image_url, prompt + 'var.jpg')

    print("Saved completed variation image as" + prompt + "var.jpg")
```

Аргумент prompt передается сразу. А version должно передаваться потом, после того как пользователь выберет версию картинки. Но я без понятия как это сделать. Как передать аргумент version не сразу?

Comment: Разбить функцию на две (до комментария `# Now, ask the user to input the version` и после)

Comment: а как данные с первой во вторую функцию передать?

Comment: `return completed_image_data` и сохранить в форму и второй функции передавать в качестве параметра